# useHistory is not exported in version 6.0.0-beta.0?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, switch-statement, version, react-router-dom

```
"react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
```

The Material UI 'Devias Material Kit Pro' template has this version and **useHistory** doesn't work, is there any other property with a different name that works the same? I used navigate.**push** (history.**push**) with **useNavigate** and it doesn't work.

**useHistory** only works for version 5.2.0?

**useHistory error**
[image: useHistoryerror]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of `react-router@6.x` this functionality has moved to the [`useNavigate`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/api-reference.md#useNavigate) hook. So the replacement for `history.push`/`history.replace` may now look like:

```ts
const { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

...
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    ...
    navigate({ pathname: './some/path' }) // instead of navigate.push
    // or
    navigate({ pathname: './some/path' }, { replace: true }) // navigate.replace
```